# Google maps : pan to a center of a geojson route clicking on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

i´m new in google maps and after reading here and there I can´t make this work.

I´m doing a google map where Im showing bike forest routes using geojson ( linestring type, are given by coordinates points).

"type": "Feature",
            "properties": { 
                "name": "larouco",
                "color":"red"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates":     [  [ -7.634432, 41.955357, 981.6 ], [ -7.635379, 41.954641, 896.1 ], [ -7.635824, 41.953955, 900.9 ] ................  ] }

All fine at the moment.

I need to pan the map to the center of the road when you clicks it.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('http://myroutes.json');

map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = feature.getProperty('color');

    return {
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeWeight: 3
    };
});

map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 8});
});

map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
});
```

here is where the problems starts

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

  var center_rute = getCenter(new google.maps.LatLngBounds());
  map.panTo(center_container);

        //map.setZoom(13);

});
```

Thinks that LatLngBounds is the way but i´m running in circles...

Thanks,
Jul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must access the `geometry` of the feature and create the `LatLngBounds` on your own by iterating over the points of the path(geometry)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qtDR6/ This example opened my eyes. Thanks for the help, Dr Molle!!!